# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validator'"

Tags: python, validation, import, module

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
 
def check_email(email):
    try:
      # validate and get info
        v = validate_email(email)
        # replace with normalized form
        email = v["email"] 
        print("True")
        return True
    except EmailNotValidError as e:
        # email is not valid, exception message is human-readable
        print(str(e))
```

I've installed `validate_email`. Trying to get this email checker to work,,,
" [https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/"](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/%22)

```
Error: "from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validator'"
```

Comment: What module did you install? Please [edit] your post and provide a link as well as the command you used to install it.

Comment: You are using the wrong name for the import.

Comment: The library you installed will work if you import it like `from validate_email import validate_email`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better install email_validator but not validate_email:
`pip install email_validator`

They are not the same library.